# How to set loader for lazy component in nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, lazy-loading, nuxt3

I am working on Nuxt 3 and I have used one of the Lazy component features of Nuxt 3 with `el-tabs` component but I need to set a custom loader when the component is loading till the component is loaded. Below is the demo code of my page

```html
<template>
<el-tabs v-model="activeTabName">
    <el-tab-pane label="Tab 1" name="tab1">
    <LazyMyComponent :data="formData" />
    </el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Tab 2" name="tab2">
    <LazyMyComponent :data="formData2" />
    </el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Tab 3" name="tab3">
    <LazyMyComponent :data="formData3" />
    </el-tab-pane>
</el-tabs>      
<template>
<script setup>
  const activeTabName = ref("tab1");
  const formData = reactive({});
  const formData2 = reactive({});
  onMounted(async () => {
    const { data, error } = await useFetch("api-url");
    if (data.value) {
      formData = data.value.data1;
      formData = data.value.data2;
    }
    if (error.value) {
      console.log(error.value);
    }
  });
</script>
```

I have tried to pass loader props and manage true false based on API response but seems loader not showing properly.

The issue occurred when the page loaded and when we change the tab the first time then the specific tab data loaded after some time then if we change or come to the loaded tab again then it worked fine.

Kindly please help me to sort out this.

Thanks in advance!